# Why Session is not accessible in Rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am very curious to know why Rails is not providing session access in model.

So I have read many articles but not getting why ?
is there any security concern?

Comment: Its just a separation of concerns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it violates the Model-View-Controller pattern. The session persists information between requests. Requests are handled by the controller, responses handled by the view. Thus, the session is only accessible in controllers and views.

A model can use session information, but it cannot access it directly. It must be passed in by a controller:

```
# controller
@my_model.do_something_with(session[:data])


# model
def do_something_with(session_data)
  session_data.do_something
end
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a great question and I don't understand why it's being down voted. I know the answer but would struggle to articulate it. I remember facing a similar confusion myself.

The controller and view are always within the context of a session but a model is not.

An oft used metaphor for MVC is a car.

- Model - The accelerator pedal
- Controller - The action of pushing the pedal
- View - The speedometer

The model may have attributes such as the position of the pedal even when it's in a box on a shelf.

```
@pedal.position = 1
```

But the view and controller will always be within the context of a session (being driven by a current_user)

Putting our foot down...

```
@pedal.update(:position, 2)
```

What speed are we going? (integrating all acceleration of the current_session / road trip)

```
current_session.speed? // = 30mph
```

It makes sense to ask "who is driving? (current_user)" when saying "Accelerate!" or "What speed are we going?"

It makes no sense to ask "Who is driving?" when looking at a car part (model) on a shelf.

However, if the model were a car driver log book then you might want to send session data to the model to update attributes of the log book.

```
@car.start!(:started_by => current_driver)
```

In summary, the controller and view are always in the context of a session. There is always someone conducting the action or observing the view.

Comment: The metaphor is obscure and hard to understand, especially to this mechanically-inclined native English speaker. It might be distracting from an otherwise good answer.

Comment: I disagree. It's *possible* to have session data in the model. It's just not advisable. There are hacks that will allow you to access session data in a model but this breaks the Law of Demeter. The controller and view are **always** in the context of a session because there's always someone or something instigating the action or observing the view.

Comment: What? We agree on the point. My comment was in reference to the particularly unhelpful accelerator pedal metaphor.